# get count of similar data based on two columns using linq & asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a DB table consists following Columns and Date.

**Table1**

```
id | CauseID(forgeinkey) | Datefrom | Title
-------------------------------------------
1  | 2 |09/10/2014 | title1

2  | 1 |09/20/2014 | title2

3  | 1 |09/20/2014 | title3

4 | 3 |09/30/2014 | title4

5 | 3 |09/30/2014 | title5
```

**Table2**

```
CauseID | Title
--------------------
1 | cause1

2 | cause2

3 | cause3
```

What i want that if user enters month 09 show the data from above table should be get in following format:

```
cause1(2)-title2-title3
```

**(beacuse cause1 occures two times in Table in 09/20/2014)**

```
cause3(2)-title4-title5
```

**(beacuse cause3 occures two times in Table in 09/30/2014)**

```
cause2(1)-title1
```

**(beacuse cause2 occures one time in Table in 09/10/2014)**

Can somebody please tell me how to do it in LINQ ASP.NET . Thank you very very much in advance

Comment: show what you have done already and where is your problem.

Comment: Do a group by on CauseID and DateFrom, and filter out the groups where there are only one match.